# How to debug the crahses of JNI interfaced lib?

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface

There is an error in my JNI lib outside of JVM.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff9037cd8de, pid=24387, tid=140708181948160
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [_MyLib-ExitOnDelete-3797760937319876478.so+0x408de] MyLib::MyLibStringImpl::inc()+0xc
#
```

It seems to happen when i try to create a temp file and then delete it on exit of the function.  but it leads to my string impl for increasing a counter inc() {return count +=1;}.  The c++ lib runs fine by itself. Only in the JNI lib, it crashes often.

Any insights?

Comment: Outside of the JVM?  Then how is that error generated?  It's from a JVM, per "Java Runtime Environment".

Comment: It happens in JNI interface code.  There I called the c++ lib function to load a .so lib, and then delete it after loading the .so file into the memory.  then this error occurs.